# Installing Quicklisp on Maxima for maxima-jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, sbcl, maxima, quicklisp

I'd like to try using maxima on jupyter (Windows). I was made aware that there is a maxima kernel for jupyter named maxima-jupyter (https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-jupyter).

I installed maxima using chocolatey and tried to follow the steps given on https://github.com/robert-dodier/maxima-jupyter. Regarding the step where I need to install Quicklisp, I tried doing it using command line maxima like this:

```
Maxima 5.44.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp SBCL 2.0.0
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) load("quicklisp.lisp");

==== quicklisp quickstart 2015-01-28 loaded ====

To continue with installation, evaluate: (quicklisp-quickstart:install)

For installation options, evaluate: (quicklisp-quickstart:help)

(%o1)                           quicklisp.lisp
(%i2) (quicklisp-quickstart:install);
(%o2)                         quicklisp - install
(%i3)
```

Quicklisp prompts me with "quicklisp - install" and I have no idea what to do next.

Did I do something wrong with my preceding steps or should I install SBCL on my device and install quicklisp using that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your interest in Maxima and Maxima-Jupyter. I apologize for the rather complex installation instructions. I see you've gotten through the first step, that's good. When Quicklisp says "evaluate <something>", it expects <something> to be evaluated as Lisp code. In Maxima you can say: `:lisp (quicklisp-quickstart:install)` or in general `:lisp <something>` to evaluate <something> as Lisp code. Give that a try. However, I see Quicklisp reports it is version 2015-01-28, which seems out of date; is there a newer version? Hope this helps.

Comment: @RobertDodier First of all, thank you for responding and thank you for maxima-jupyter! As for installing quicklisp on maxima, I think I have addressed this albeit through a different way. What I did was I ran the SBCL executable and installed quicklisp just how one would through SBCL. However, I seem to be encountering a much less descriptive error: `While evaluating the form starting at line 4, column 0
  of #P"C:/Users/PC/downloads/maxima-jupyter-master/load-maxima-jupyter.lisp":
;
; compilation unit aborted` Does this indicate a faulty quicklisp installation or is it something else?